# exception occurs when using MappedByteBuffer's READ_Write mode

Tags: java

I want to test `MappedByteBuffer`'s  READ_WRITE mode. But I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.channels.NonWritableChannelException
 at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:755)
 at test.main(test.java:13)
```

I have no idea have to fix it. 
Thanks in advance.

**now I fix the program and there is no exception. But the system returns a sequence of Garbage characters, but in fact there is just a string "asdfghjkl" in the file in.txt . I guess may be the coding scheme cause this problem, but i do not know how to verify it and fix it.**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    File f= new File("./in.txt");
    RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rws");
    FileChannel fc = in.getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, f.length());

    while(mbb.hasRemaining())
        System.out.print(mbb.getChar());
    fc.close();
    in.close();

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileInputStream` is for reading only and you are using `FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE`. It should be `READ` for `FileInputStream`. Use `RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw");` for `READ_WRITE` map.

**EDIT:**
The character in your file is probably 8 bit, and java uses 16 bit characters. Hence the getChar will read two bytes instead of single byte.

Use `get()` method and cast it to `char` to get your desired character:

```
while(mbb.hasRemaining())
        System.out.print((char)mbb.get());
```

Alternatively, since the file is probably US-ASCII based, you can use `CharsetDecoder` to obtain a `CharBuffer`, for instance:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class TestFC {
        public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException{
                File f = new File("in.txt");
                try(RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rws"); FileChannel fc = in.getChannel();) {
                        MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, f.length());

                        Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
                        CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
                        CharBuffer cb = decoder.decode(mbb);

                        for(int i=0; i<cb.limit();i++) {
                                System.out.print(cb.get(i));
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

will give you desired results as well.

Comment: @Charles Menguy Thanks for formatting. Did you use backticks to mark the code?

Comment: thanks for your help. now I have another problem, please see my problem again i have edited it

Answer (score 1):

Acc. to Javadocs:

> **NonWritableChannelException** - If the mode is READ_WRITE or PRIVATE but this channel was not opened for both reading and writing
>
> **FileInputStream** - is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data.
>
> **RandomAccessFile** - Instances of this class support both reading and writing to a random access file

In place of `FileInputStream`, Use `RandomAccessFile`.